# How to count orders with positions unwind in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: count, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have a collection with order headers and positions (as array) and I need an query which should give me:

- quantity of customers
- quantity of orders
- summed up order value

all grouped by date and order type. I already got this covered by two queries (see below), but I want to have it in one.
The main problem to me is that I need to count the orders but with positions unwinded.

E.g.: Below would be a possible result of the combined query with the test data below:

```
/* 1 */
{
       "_id" : {
        "typ" : "WERBUNG",
        "date" : "2017-07-08"
    },
    "orderQuantity" : 1.0,
    "value" : 1000,
    "customerQuantity" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "typ" : "WERBUNG",
        "date" : "2017-07-07"
    },
    "orderQuantity" : 2.0,
    "value" : 100,
    "customerQuantity" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "typ" : "ANDERE",
        "date" : "2017-07-08"
    },
    "orderQuantity" : 4.0,
    "value" : 1500,
    "customerQuantity" : 4
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "typ" : "ANDERE",
        "date" : "2017-07-07"
    },
    "orderQuantity" : 1.0,
    "value" : 90,
    "customerQuantity" : 1
}
```

... this would mean:

- On 7-7 there where 3 orders (WERBUNG 2, ANDERE 1) for only 1 customer (WERBUNG 1, ANDERE 1 - will be counted twice here, bit this would be okay)
- On 8-7 there where 5 orders (WERBUNG 1, ANDERE 4) for 5 customers (WERBUNG 4, ANDERE 1)

I have an idea that SortBy would help here, however we still use 3.2 - so no access to this stage (and some other usefull options as well...).

Cheers!

--
Some information which might help:

// Here are the sample orders:

```
/*1*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596075d5be8fc415341c7d43"),
    "header" : {
        "kundennummer" : "820130",
        "auftragsdatum" : 0,
        "bestellangaben" : "BLOCK1",
        "information1" : "blocktest",
        "erstellungsdatum" : 1499493785.25906,
        "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475000,
    },
    "ordertype" : "BLOCK1",
    "customernnummer" : "820130",
    "ordernumber" : 87475000,
    "positions" : [ 
            "artikelnummer" : 1985900,
            "menge" : 1,
            "bruttopreis" : 1000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("596075d5be8fc415341c7d45")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-08",
    "type" : "WERBUNG"
}
/*2*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59608f64be8fc415341c7d46"),
    "header" : {
       "kundennummer" : "944867",
       "auftragsdatum" : 0,
       "bestellangaben" : "",
       "information1" : "blocktest",
       "erstellungsdatum" : 1499500356.10022,
       "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475001,
    },
    "ordertype" : "",
    "customernnummer" : "944867",
    "ordernumber" : 87475001,
    "positions" : [ 
        {
            "artikelnummer" : 4029300,
            "menge" : 1,
            "bruttopreis" : 100,
            "_id" : ObjectId("59608f64be8fc415341c7d5c")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-08",
    "type" : "ANDERE"
}
/*3*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5960925ebe8fc415341c7d5d"),
    "header" : {
       "kundennummer" : "981927",
       "auftragsdatum" : 0,
       "bestellangaben" : "",
       "information1" : "blocktest",
       "erstellungsdatum" : 1499501036.34265,
       "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475002,
    },
    "ordertype" : "",
    "customernnummer" : "981927",
    "ordernumber" : 87475002,
    "positions" : [ 
            },
            "artikelnummer" : 4557300,
            "menge" : 2,
            "bruttopreis" : 100,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5960925ebe8fc415341c7d74")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-08",
    "type" : "ANDERE"
}
/*4*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5960925ebe8fc415341c7d75"),
    "header" : {
      "kundennummer" : "981927",
      "auftragsdatum" : 0,
      "bestellangaben" : "BLOCK2",
      "information1" : "blocktest",
      "erstellungsdatum" : 1499414714,
      "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475003,
    },
    "ordertype" : "BLOCK2",
    "customernnummer" : "981927",
    "ordernumber" : 87475003,
    "positions" : [ 
        {   "artikelnummer" : 7081200,
            "menge" : 3,
            "bruttopreis" : 10,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5960925ebe8fc415341c7d8f")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-07",
    "type" : "WERBUNG"
}
/*5*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596093ebbe8fc415341c7d90"),
    "header" : {
      "kundennummer" : "962422",
      "auftragsdatum" : 0,
      "bestellangaben" : "",
      "information1" : "blocktest",
      "erstellungsdatum" : 1499501507.75201,
      "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475004,
    },
    "ordertype" : "",
    "customernnummer" : "962422",
    "ordernumber" : 87475004,
    "positions" : [ 
            "artikelnummer" : 3545900,
            "menge" : 4,
            "bruttopreis" : 100,
            "_id" : ObjectId("596093ebbe8fc415341c7d95")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-08",
    "type" : "ANDERE"
}
/*6*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596098e9be8fc415341c7ddf"),
    "header" : {
      "kundennummer" : "981927",
      "auftragsdatum" : 0,
      "bestellangaben" : "BLOCK3",
      "information1" : "blocktest",
      "erstellungsdatum" : 1499415886,
      "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475007,
    },
    "ordertype" : "BLOCK3",
    "customernnummer" : "981927",
    "ordernumber" : 87475007,
    "positions" : [ 
        {
            "artikelnummer" : 1006199,
            "menge" : 7,
            "bruttopreis" : 10,
            "_id" : ObjectId("596098e9be8fc415341c7de6")
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-07",
    "type" : "WERBUNG"
}
/*7*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59609a47be8fc415341c7de7"),
    "header" : {
      "kundennummer" : "981225",
      "auftragsdatum" : 0,
      "bestellangaben" : "",
      "information1" : "blocktest",
      "erstellungsdatum" : 1499503113.21714,
    },
    "ordertype" : "",
    "customernnummer" : "981225",
    "ordernumber" : 87475008,
    "positions" : [ 
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("59609a47be8fc415341c7e0d")
            "artikelnummer" : 2308400,
            "menge" : 8,
            "bruttopreis" : 100,
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-08",
    "type" : "ANDERE"
}
/*8*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59609a47be8fc415341c7e0e"),
    "header" : {
      "vorgabeauftragsnummer" : 87475009,
      "erstellungsdatum" : 1499416697,
      "information1" : "blocktest",
      "bestellangaben" : "",
      "auftragsdatum" : 0,
      "kundennummer" : "981927",
    },
    "ordertype" : "",
    "customernnummer" : "981927",
    "ordernumber" : 87475009,
    "positions" : [ 
            "_id" : ObjectId("59609a47be8fc415341c7e57"),
            "bruttopreis" : 10,
            "menge" : 9,
            "artikelnummer" : 8017000
        }
    ],
    "date" : "2017-07-07",
    "type" : "ANDERE"
}
```

// Query 1: Quantity of customers and order value by order type (WERBUNG, ANDERE) and day

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
{$unwind:"$positions"},
    {$project: {
        "_id": 1,
        customer: "$header.customernnummer",
        date: {$}ToString: {format: "%d-%m-%Y", }: {"$add":[ new }(0), {"$multiply": [1000, "$header.erstellungsdate"]}]} }},
        edate: "$header.erstellungsdate",
        ordertype: "$header.ordertype",
        type: {$cond: { if: {$ne: ["$header.ordertype" ,""]} , then: "WERBUNG", else: "ANDERE"  }},
        value: {$multiply: ["$positions.price","$positions.quantity"]},
        }
    },
    {$group: {
        _id: {type: "$type", tag: "$date",customer: "$customer" },
        type: {$first: "$type"},
        date: {$first: "$date"},
        wert: {$sum: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {$project:{
        _id : 0,
        customer: "$customer",
        type: "$type",
        date: "$date",
        wert: "$wert"
        }
    }
    ,{$group: {
        _id: {typ: "$type", date: "$date"}, customerQuantity:{$sum:1},
        value: {$sum: "$wert"}
        }
    },
    {$sort:{
        typ: 1, date: -1
        }
    }
]}
```

// Query 2: Order quantity by type, date

```
...
{$project: {
    block: {$cond: { if: {$ne: ["$auftragskopf.bestellangaben" ,""]} , then: "WERBUNG", else: "ANDERE"  }},
    datum: {$dateToString: {format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: {"$add":[ new Date(0), {"$multiply": [1000, "$auftragskopf.erstellungsdatum"]}]} }},
    }
},
{$group:{
    _id: {block: "$block", datum: "$datum"},
    auftragsanzahl:{$sum:1},
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how your data looks like, but I understand from this line

```
type: {$cond: { if: {$ne: ["$header.ordertype" ,""]} , then: "WERBUNG", else: "ANDERE"  }}
```

that if your **$header.ordertype** is WERBUNG then you want your order type to be **WERBUNG** otherwise its **ANDERE**. With that in mind here is my solution.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  {
        $project: {
            "_id": 1,
            header: 1,
            positions: 1,
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: {
                        "$add": [new Date(0), {
                            "$multiply": [1000, "$header.date"]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            type: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$header.ordertype", "WERBUNG"]
                    },
                    then: "WERBUNG",
                    else: "ANDERE"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                type: "$type",
                date: "$date"
            },
            werbungCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$type', 'WERBUNG']
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            andereCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$type', 'ANDERE']
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            customer: {
                $first: "$header.customernnummer"
            },
            date: {
                $first: "$date"
            },
            type: {
                $first: "$type"
            },
            positions: {
                $first: "$positions"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$positions"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 1,
            customer: "$customer",
            date: 1,
            ordertype: "$header.ordertype",
            type: "$type",
            value: {
                $multiply: ["$positions.price", "$positions.quantity"]
            },
            price: "$positions.price",
            quantity: "$positions.quantity",
            orderQuantity: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$type", "WERBUNG"]
                    },
                    then: "$werbungCount",
                    else: "$andereCount"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                type: "$type",
                tag: "$date",
                customer: "$customer"
            },
            type: {
                $first: "$type"
            },
            date: {
                $first: "$date"
            },
            wert: {
                $sum: "$value"
            },
            orderQuantity: {
                $first: "$orderQuantity"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                typ: "$type",
                date: "$date"
            },
            orderQuantity: {
                $first: "$orderQuantity"
            },
            value: {
                $sum: "$wert"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            typ: 1,
            date: -1
        }
    }
])
```

I use the first **$project** to "normalize" the date. So an order placed at *1499415886: Friday, July 7, 2017 8:24:46 AM* and *1499415990: Friday, July 7, 2017 8:26:30 AM* will both be counted since they are on the same date (cause I could also tell from what you wrote that the time doesn't matter to you, only the date)

In the **$group** after the **$project** you just count the documents that have the "ordertype" WERBUNG and set them to the field **werbungCount**, otherwise if they are empty set them to the field **andereCount**. The pipeline after the **$project** and the **$group** is like you did it. I just corrected some mistakes and changed the name of the fields in some spots. Also added the **orderQuantity** field with a condition on the second **$project**.

Hope that works!